# How can I fix double running function in firebase and react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am trying to check existing of data on firebase real-time database and then add new data.
When I add exist data, it works well.
When I add new data, it works two time and don't add new data.

```
registerStaff = async (model) => {
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    return false;
  }
  if (model) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.ref("tbl_phone_number").on("value", async (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          const samePhone = await _.filter(snapshot.val(), (o) => {
            `find same phone number`;
            return o.phone.toString() === model.phone.toString();
          });
          console.log("checking...", snapshot.val());
          if (samePhone.length > 0) {
            `checking samephone Number`;
            console.log("exist...");
            `if exist, return error`;
            resolve({
              type: "phone",
              message: "The phone number is already used.",
            });
          } else {
            `If there is no, add new phone number`;
            const newPostKey = this.db
              .ref()
              .child("tbl_phone_number")
              .push().key;
            this.db
              .ref(`tbl_phone_number/${newPostKey}`)
              .set({ phone: model.phone, type: model.type })
              .then(() => {
                console.log("making...==>");
                resolve({
                  type: "success",
                  message: "Successfully registered.",
                });
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                resolve({
                  type: "phone",
                  message: "Sorry. Something went wrong",
                });
              });
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
};

//console log result checking... checking... exist... checking... exist... making...
```

Comment: a minimal creation exampletais is needed. usually wrapping this function in `useEffect(() => {}, [])` will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to solve this problem in using function "on" and "once".
'on' function of firebase is used to keep data from firebase and add new data automatically when I add new data.
'once' function of firebase is used to change data only once.
Therefore in above question, if I use 'once' function instead of 'on', it will work well.
Good luck.